# What does variance mean in maximum likelihood estimation?

Tags: machine-learning, mathematical-statistics, maximum-likelihood, multivariate-analysis

Using maximum likelihood estimation, we find $\sigma^2$ to be the variance for a single variable and the $\sigma^2$ becomes $\Sigma$, a covariance matrix, for a multivariate normal distribution. Does the variance, $\sigma^2$, mean that it has the smallest variance with the highest peak? I am wondering what find a maximum likelihood estimate for a variance or a matrix of variances and covariances mean.

Comment: Language use, terminology and concepts problematic, e.g.,  $\sigma^2$ is variance, not $\sigma$.

Comment: What does it mean that "$\sigma^2$ becomes a covariance matrix"? What does "it" in "it has the smallest variance with highest peak" refer to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you think about a Gaussian, then the variance measures how "wide" is the bell. This means that there is a higher probability that some values are far from the mean. On the other case, with a small variance you have a thin bell, meaning that the probability of having values that are far from the mean is very low. 
For a Maximum Likelihood problem in a multivariate case, you have a covariance matrix, often diagonal, that evaluates the variance of each normal distribution, along with an array of the relative means. Now, since the ML solution is the one with the highest probability, it will be a value that is somehow close to all the means of every normal distribution (since this is where they have the maximum probability). The variance of each distribution, anyway, tells you how much you can expect that solution to move far from the mean of the respective normal distribution: a very low variance means that the distribution is very thin, so a solution that is far from its mean has a very low probability, lowering in this way the total probability of the solution. On the other hand, an high variance means that your solution can be moved away from the relative mean without lowering too much the probability of it. 
It is often intuitive to think of it as a mass-spring problem: imagine your mean to be the place where you place a spring. Then the variance tells you how "hard" it is to stretch that spring. Now, generalize it to n-dimensions with n-spring, and you will have stronger and weaker springs, thus making it easier to move in certain directions and harder in other directions.